# ASP.NET Core TagHelper input asp-for rendering value attribute sticks with original value in request model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I build up a simple web page with asp.net core 3.1 for reproducing problem. There are 2 action in same `HomeController.cs`.

one for rendering a html form, another for receiving form post data then rendering form again.

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        // rendering form
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var myForm = new MyForm();
            myForm.Id = 100;
            return View("index", myForm);
        }

        // after form post, rendering form with updated value.
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(MyForm m)
        {
            m.Id = 200;
            return View("index", m);
        }
}
```

I use [asp.net core tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in `index.cshtml`

```html
@model MyForm

<div>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
        <span>@Model.Id</span>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Id"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I GET /index, everything is fine, both @Model.Id in span and input value are 100

Http Response for Get /index

```html
<form method="post" action="/">
        <span>100</span>
        <input type="text" data-val="true" 
               data-val-required="The Id field is required."
               id="Id" name="Id" value="100">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But When I post form, I expected both value in span and input should be 200, but it is 200 in span and 100 in form

Http Response for POST /index with 100 in input

```html
<form method="post" action="/">
        <span>200</span>
        <input type="text" data-val="true" 
               data-val-required="The Id field is required."
               id="Id" name="Id" value="100">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I guess "asp-for" choose to read data from original ModelState, which is built while modelbinding. Instead of read ViewModel passed for view Razor rendering.

Does Anyone know why tag helper `asp-for` behavior like this? How should I avoid this behavior and make `asp-for` use the Model I passed in View("index", m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess "asp-for" choose to read data from original ModelState

Yes, this is by design. Default TagHelper display ModelState value not Model.

If you want `asp-for` display the updated model value, you could add `ModelState.Clear();` in your post action.

```
public IActionResult Index(MyForm m)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    m.Id = 200;
    return View("index", m);
}
```

Comment: Wow, Works like a charm. Do you know  why tag helper designs like this?